SharePoint Online - finding direct assignments
We have 600+ SharePoint sites and we are going to migrate them to an entirely new hybrid domain environment. We are currently attempting a configuration of a cross-tenant access scenario. I am attempting to find any users who have been directly assigned to any of our SharePoint sites. I don't want to go user by user (3000+ users) to find direct assignments unless I absolutely have to. I would rather look at the sites and determine if a user is not assigned as a part of a group. So far I am not finding a SPO cmdlet that will identify the direct assigned users.
Has anyone done this before, and if so would you be willing to share your methods and experience? I can assign all of the current users/groups but would rather clean up before migrating the sites from the old tenant to the new tenant. I have successfully assigned my account in the new tenant as an #EXT user to an existing site in the old tenant. But we are wanting to avoid direct assignments it at all possible.
I am pulling the sites into a collection with Get-SPOSite, and users/groups for each site with Get-SPOUser. From there I need to identify direct assignments and that isn't clear. TIA.
